# Media queries not working after pushing from local to Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I added media queries to my local wp-theme and the work fine locally. However, after I pushed the changes to staging site the media queries doesn't execute. Other changes not related to media queries work.

I checked the files through the staging wp-admin theme editor and the correct files are imported. But when I check dev tools on my staging site they media queries doesn't show at all. I use the same browser as my local environment, just different tabs. See screenshots of my local site and my staging site, in this example the div poem-card.

[Local site, the width of the div is 88% as according to media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqsKX.png)

[Staging site, no media queries execute or even visible in the dev tool, width of div is 30%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MptM.png)

I also pushed the code directly to my live site, skipping the staging part but it gave the same result there.

In my code I have this in my header

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And here are my media queries and they work fine locally. I just can't find where the problem is, since it works locally in Wordpress I don't even know if it's a code thing.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.poem-card {
    width: 96%;

}

main {
    padding:5px; 
}

.site-header{
    padding: 20px; 
}
.article-bok {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.text-bok {
    width: 96%; 
    
}
.bild-bok {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 96%; 
    }

ul {
padding-inline-start: 0; 
}
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .poem-card {
        width: 88%; 
    }   
    main {
        padding:10px; 
    }   
    .text-dikt {
        width: 80%;  
}
.article-bok {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.text-bok {
    width: 96%; 
    
}
.bild-bok {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 96%; 
    }

}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .poem-card {
        width: 43%;
    }
    main {
        padding:20px; 
    }   } 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .poem-card {
        width: 28%;
    }
    .article-bok {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .text-bok {
        width: 40%; 
        
    }
    .bild-bok {
        margin-top: 40px;
        width: 44%; 
        }   }
```

Comment: Have you _verified_ that the stylesheet delivered from your online site actually contains these rules? Have you validated your HTML & CSS? Does the browser console show any errors?

Comment: I've checked the files in W3 validator, and yes I have checked that my online site actually have all the media queries in it's css file. The browser console shows no errors.